# How do I fix the error "include errors detected. Please update your includePath"

Tags: eosio-code

Im following along with the getting started guide and I got up to the [first contract](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/your-first-contract) section in 2.1, I made the hello directory and cd into it, I touched hello.cpp and then opened it in VS Code, once I added the header

```
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
```

I got the red error squiggle, I do have the c++ extension for vs code installed, the error is

```
 include errors detected. Please update your includePath eosio/eosio.hpp
```

Answer (score 3):

I installed `eosio.cdt` with brew. Adding `/usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.6.3/opt/eosio.cdt/include/**` to my includePath variable helped me

For eosio.cdt 1.7.0, the path is:
`/usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.7.0/opt/eosio.cdt/include/eosiolib/core/**`

Answer (score 0):

Because eosio-cpp builder is automatically find and include the eosio/eosio.hpp.

So Visual studio don't know where is the eosio folder.
You have to check the eosio.cdt version. It must be 1.6.x, not 1.5.x version

And If you check the version. you can build the hello.cpp by using the eosio-cpp

```
eosio-cpp hello.cpp -o hello.wasm --abigen
```

you can see hello.wasm , hello.abi

Comment: You are indeed correct I can build it, but the question is really about how to get rid of the error in VS Code, how do i find the eosio folder? I installed it with brew on the mac, and once i do find it how do I tell VS Code where it is?

Comment: eosio folder is located in eosio.cdt folder. the path is /usr/local/eosio.cdt/include

Comment: No such path on a Mac

Comment: eosio-cpp is running??

Comment: yes I can run `eosio-cpp hello.cpp -o hello.wasm ` with no problem

Comment: ~/include/eosiolib is the folder that you want

Comment: Thank you, that directory exists and looks good, I guess the last part of the answer is how to tell VS Code about it so it stops showing the errors

Comment: Any text editor don't build the eosio contract. Because eosio contract doesn't use gcc g++ ,only use eosio-cpp. So you have to follow the eosio-cpp.